# How to get an upload message for every file you upload in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, file-upload

This is the code in view where the content is displayed after upload.

```
<h3>Additional Documents</h3>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($doc_data as $value) { ?>
        <li><a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo base_url() . $value['upload']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery"> <img src="<?php echo base_url() . $value['upload']; ?>" height="160" /></a>
            <?php if ($value['approved'] == 1) { ?>
                <div class="approved-sm"></div>
            <?php } elseif ($value['approved'] == 0) { ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <!--<a style="border:none;" href="<?php echo base_url() . '?id=' . $value['']; ?>"><input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger"></a>--> 
            <a style="border:none;" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'home/universityDelImg?id=' . $value['id']; ?>">
                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
            </a> </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



    <?php


 if($fileuploaded){

    print_r($fileuploaded);
    die();

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>".$fileuploaded."</div>";
   }   

?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/uploadFile?uid='<?php $t = time();
    echo $t; ?>'" style=" background: #ec7266 none repeat scroll 0 0;
   border: medium none;
   color: #fff;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   font-size: 17px;
   font-weight: 700;
   height: 44px;
   padding: 10px 20px;;" >Upload additional document</a>
</div>
</div>
```

In controller i have made these functions 'uploadFile' and 'uploadAdd' which are getting called.

```
public function uploadFile() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('university_id')) {

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('university_id');
        $data['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $data['user_data'] = $this->home_model->user_profile_data($user_id);

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
            if (isset($_FILES['image1']['name']) && $_FILES['image1']['name'] != '') {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/';
                $imagename1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
                $getimage_extension = explode(".", $imagename1);
                $imagename1 = $getimage_extension[1];
                $imagename1 = strtotime("now") . '.' . $imagename1;
                $_FILES['image1']['name'] = $imagename1;
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
                $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');
                if (isset($_FILES['image1']['name']) && $_FILES['image1']['name'] != '') {
                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image1')) {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->uploads->display_errors());
                    } else {
                        $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                        $imagename1 = $imagename1;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $imagename1 = '';
            }
            $useremail = $this->input->post('user_email');
            $user_feedback = $this->input->post('user_feedback');
            $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');

            $data_to_store = array(
                'user_name' => $useremail,
                'user_email' => $useremail,
                'user_feedback' => $user_feedback,
                'user_attachment' => $imagename1,
            );
        }


        $this->load->view('home/new-header', $data);
        $data['get_social'] = $this->home_model->get_social();
        $this->load->view('home/left_university_sidebar', $data);
//$this->load->view('socail', $data);

        $this->load->view('uploadFile', $data);
        $this->load->view('home/footer');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('home/header');

        $this->load->view('signin');

        $this->load->view('home/footer');
    }
}

function uploadAdd() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('university_id')) {

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {

            $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/';



            if (isset($_FILES['image1']['name']) && $_FILES['image1']['name'] != '') {

                $imagename1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];

                $getimage_extension = explode(".", $imagename1);

                $extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

                $imagename1 = $getimage_extension[1];

                if (!in_array($imagename1, $extension)) {

                    $imagename1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
                } else {

                    $imagename1 = strtotime("now") . '.' . $imagename1;
                }


                $_FILES['image1']['name'] = $imagename1;

                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['image1']['name'];

                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

                $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');

                if (isset($_FILES['image1']['name']) && $_FILES['image1']['name'] != '') {

                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image1')) {

                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
// $this->upload->message="File Uploaded Successfully!";
// $this->upload->success= TRUE;
                    } else {

                        $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                $data['fileuploaded'] = "Your file successfully uploaded!";
           $this->load->view("university_document",$data);
                        $imagename1 = $imagename1;
                    }
                }
            }

            $data['success'] = $this->home_model->insert_mustuffaddUniversity($imagename1);
            $data['flash_message'] = TRUE;
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message_success", "<font class='error'>Added successfully.</font>");
            **log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
            **
        } else {

            $this->university();
        }
        redirect("university_document");
    } else {

        $this->load->view('home/header');

        $this->load->view('signin');

        $this->load->view('home/footer');
    }
}
```

I am also uploading the uploadFile which is getting called in views basically. I tried using logs to get error message which basically is shown in the logs also. But i am not able to put the personalized message on the page after every upload.

```
<h2 class="title">Upload Additional Document</h2>
<div class="mystuff-block">
<div data-example-id="togglable-tabs" role="tabpanel" class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
   <?php if (isset($success)) { ?>
      <span style="color:green;"><?php print_r($success); ?></span>
      <?php } else if (isset($email_exist)) { ?>
         <span style="color:red;"><?php print_r($success); ?></span>
         <?php } ?>
      <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <?php if (isset($messg)) {  echo $messg ; } ?>
   <div class="upload-block">
      <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/uploadAdd" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input name="userid" type="hidden" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
         <label>Upload</label>
         <span style="color:red;" id="eror"></span>
         <div class="file-upload-outer">
            <div class="fileUpload btn"> <span></span>
               <input type="file" class="upload file-control" name="image1" id="upload_image" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload"  id="stuff">
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

[university_document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Kml.png)

[uploadFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3snr.png)

Comment: Can you help me solve this issue? @Little Phild

Comment: What is your code outputting.

Comment: It shows nothing. Basically it uploads the content and shows me the content uploaded. But i didn't get get any user defined message like content has been uploaded.

Comment: So you just want to alert the user that the file has been uploaded?

Comment: Exactly. One every upload i want that!

Comment: Alright let me update my answer

Comment: sure. Take your time!

Comment: I have updated my answer please try it out and give me the feedback

Comment: I had updated the code with the changes you said. But i am not able to get the echo message as such. But when i use print_r($fileuploaded) then i am able to get it. Without that it shows error in logs like undefined variable

Comment: Can you paste here the results :)

Comment: ERROR - 2016-01-14 11:34:36 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: fileuploaded C:\wamp\www\acadview_webapplicaiton\application\views\university_document.php 361

Comment: @vijaysehgal Thats not best option. If multiple image upload, show one message with uploaded images

Comment: Oh i got you. Even i don't mind doing that as well. But i want to be open in both the cases.

Comment: Provide your latest codes

Comment: Also update the view and include  `filenames` such as **toolset.php**

Comment: I already updated the view part above in my code. But i didn't get you for filename. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

In your Addfile function search for this line and in your `$data` array append another data like below example.

```
    function uploadAdd() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('university_id')) {

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {

            $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/';



            if (isset($_FILES['image1']['name']) && $_FILES['image1']['name'] != '') {

                $imagename1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];

                $getimage_extension = explode(".", $imagename1);

                $extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

                $imagename1 = $getimage_extension[1];

                if (!in_array($imagename1, $extension)) {

                    $imagename1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
                } else {

                    $imagename1 = strtotime("now") . '.' . $imagename1;
                }


                $_FILES['image1']['name'] = $imagename1;

                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['image1']['name'];

                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

                $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');

                if (isset($_FILES['image1']['name']) && $_FILES['image1']['name'] != '') {

                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image1')) {

                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
// $this->upload->message="File Uploaded Successfully!";
// $this->upload->success= TRUE;
                    } else {
                        $imagename1 = $imagename1;
                    }
                }
            }

            $data['success'] = $this->home_model->insert_mustuffaddUniversity($imagename1);
            $data['flash_message'] = TRUE;
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message_success", "<font class='error'>Added successfully.</font>");
            #log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a     value.');
              $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
              $data['fileuploaded'] = "Your file successfully uploaded!";
              $this->load->view("university_document",$data);
        } else {

            $this->university();
        }
        redirect("university_document");
    } else {

        $this->load->view('home/header');

        $this->load->view('signin');

        $this->load->view('home/footer');
    }
}
```

And then in your `view`

```
    if($fileuploaded){
           echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>".$fileuploaded."</div>";
   }
```

Comment: Hey, What is the filename.php here? Is that the view file which shows the uploaded content?

Comment: Replace `filename.php` with your view file name

Comment: See i am doing in this way in upload_document(view file) where i want it to be viewed :- <?php


 if($fileuploaded){

    print_r($fileuploaded);
    die();
    
     echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>".$fileuploaded."</div>";
   }

?>

Comment: I am able to get the message when i use print_r but without that it doesn't call that $data[fileuploaded]

Comment: No again same error undefined variable. Actually the function(uploadAdd) is getting called. So when i am uploading the document that is another page and when i have uploaded it. The uploaded content which appears on the page is basically another page. So on that page i want the message to appear which is 'university_document' page.

Comment: Alright: But in the above code are you redirecting over here `$this->load->view("university_document.php",$data);` **OR** your redirecting using `redirect("university_document.php")`

Comment: So you want me to do in this way - redirect("university_document.php") instead of $this->load->view("university_document.php",$data);

Comment: Actually I made a mistake instead of `$this->load->view("university_document.php",$data)` change it to `$this->load->view("university_document",$data)`

Comment: When including a view in Codeigniter you don't include the file extension :P

Comment: True :-) But this is not even helping. My error is still the same. And not getting called on the same page.

Comment: Another thing to notice: The name of the file maybe it doesn't match with a view name. Or you misspelled the variable name

Comment: Which function are you using `uploadFile()` OR `uploadAdd()`

Comment: uploadAdd() is being used

Comment: I got this : ERROR - 2016-01-14 14:56:59 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: fileuploaded C:\wamp\www\acadview_webapplicaiton\application\views\university_document.php 361

Comment: This only works when i use print_r(expression) with die. It doesn't work in the other way.

Comment: This is not helping me out. Can you please suggest other way out?

Comment: Okay! Well in that case you should try to implement it out in all possible ways if you can. If this shows output to you? Because with print_r its showing the output but why its not able to call without that.

Comment: So how is it displaying the output if you use `print_r`. Can you past here the output

Comment: Menu
Upload Files

Additional Documents

Your file successfully uploaded!  This is the output i am getting and the url shows the uploadAdd part.

Comment: Oh i guess you didn't get it. I am saying that the message should appear on the document page where the uploaded content is shown. Not on the uploadAdd page. That is why i wrote the message part in the uploadAdd fuction and i am calling it in the university_document part.

Comment: If you want to display that message in a different page not the one that your being redirected after file upload then you should set your message into a `session variable` then that  will be possible to access your message across the website.

Comment: I have uploaded the images as well. So 1st one university_Document is the one where i am getting the uploaded files. There is a button upload additional document. On clicking on that button you get redirected to another page which is of uploading a file. There i upload a file and it automatically redirects me to the old page i.e university_document. So this is where i want msg to be shown.

Comment: No i don't want the session variable concept.